# Power BI : we are unable to connect please delete your credentials and try again later (Sharepoint)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, credentials

Currently my other team already grant me an access to their data source folder in sharepoint
im able to access the share folder but unfortunately when i open the power bi i face some credential issue.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

im able to solve the issue by check the "use my default web browser" at Authentication Browser on Power BI

[image]

Comment: This definitely does help, I was struggling with this issue from 2 hours. Finally connected.